# I get the message "This is not an Azure AD B2C directory..." for my Azure AD B2C tenant

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

I have an Azure AD B2C tenant and when I go to the 'Overview' tab, I see the following message:

```
This is not an Azure AD B2C directory. To create a new B2C directory & manage your consumer identities in the cloud, click the articles below.
```

I don't understand why this is being displayed, and what the implications would be.
I thought that it was impossible to have a tenant without a directory.
How do I fix this issue?

Comment: Are you using following article to create Azure B2C tenant?
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/tutorial-create-tenant
Did you switch your directory to B2C?
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/tutorial-create-tenant#select-your-b2c-tenant-directory

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think what you see should be this prompt:

[image]

The reason is that you are currently logged in to the directory of the Azure AD tenant and not the directory of the Azure B2C tenant. When you click the Azure AD B2C tab in the Azure AD tenant directory, you will receive this prompt.

So, make sure you [have a B2C tenant](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/tutorial-create-tenant), and then select **Directory + Subscription** filter in the top menu of the Azure portal, and then [select the directory that contains Azure AD B2C tenants](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/tutorial-create-tenant#select-your-b2c-tenant-directory).

[image]

Comment: Hmm interesting. Does this mean that a single directory cannot contain both an Azure AD tenant and an Azure AD B2C tenant?

Comment: @Attilah  Of course, a single directory cannot contain both Azure AD tenants and Azure AD B2C tenants.

Comment: @Attilah  Hi, if my answer is helpful for you, you can accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In my case Azure Portals incapability to update (and show) the newly created (B2C) directory was the problem. A logout / login solved this.

I am unaware how much time needs to pass though ;).